# Optimize code for loop for over 100,000 rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, optimization, rows

I have a dataset of more than 100,000 rows and a few columns.

What I'm trying to achieve is looking up values in another range and if it matches, put it in the column next to it. If there's more than one value that matches, insert another row and put that in.

However, the code takes forever to load and my excel ends up crashing... HELP!

```
Sub Splitter_Step1a()

Dim RefSheet As Worksheet
Set RefSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RefList")
Dim ProdSheet As Worksheet
Set ProdSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products")

Dim Brand, LastBrand, BrandList As Range
Set LastBrand = RefSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set BrandList = RefSheet.Range(RefSheet.Range("A1"), LastBrand)

Dim Reference, ReferenceList, LastReference As Range
Set LastReference = ProdSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)
Set ReferenceList = ProdSheet.Range(ProdSheet.Range("C2"), LastReference)

Dim BrandInList As Boolean

'Part 1a - assigning brand references to product
For Each Brand In BrandList
For Each Reference In ReferenceList
    If InStr(1, Reference, Brand, 1) And IsEmpty(Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
        Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
        BrandInList = True
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
        If InStr(1, Reference, Brand, 1) Then

        Reference.EntireRow.Insert
        Reference.Offset(1, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
        BrandInList = True
        End If
    Else
        BrandInList = False
    End If
Next Reference
Next Brand

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I'm looking for ways to alter the code to not use loops altogether or find a way so that excel does not crash and the macro can be run in less than 5 minutes..

**EDIT2**
My reflist is a column with cells that look something like this:

```
Howell Michigan
1234 Detroit Michigan
ABC Detroit Michigan
A Detroit Michigan
Ann Arbor Michigan
334 Ann Arbor Michigan
Amazing Howell & Detroit Kind
```

My brandlist looks like this:

```
column A       column b
Howell         Howell Michigan
Detroit        Detroit Michigan
Ann Arbor      Ann Arbor Michigan
```

The goal of this project is 2 parts:

 part 1 - if the reference cell includes what is in column A it will return whatever is in column b in the cell next to the reference cell.

 part 2 - if there is more than one occurrence (e.g. Howell & Detroit), return the first column b value in the cell next to reference cell, then insert a new row and copy everything but put second column b value instead (hence, SPLIT)

Comment: I think you can use `COUNTIF()` to "put it in the column next to it" and use `COPY() + PASTE() + REMOVEDUPLICATES() + Sort()` to "insert another row and put that in" --- Can you put a short example

Comment: If you could add three columns: samples of RefList, samples of Products and sample of RefList after the execution

Comment: You can use Table format to add your example, like this: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Is `reflist` a single-column set of data, or are there more columns associated with it? If there are other columns do any of them have formulas?

Comment: yes there is one more column next to the reflist with formulas

Comment: I think you can't do this using Excel Formulas (without VBA) so the best thing to do is O(n^2) like your code is doing. Sorry man you can only do something like this. I will add a code just to help try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you write a value in a cell Excel has to redraw your screen. so something that will help to your code is turning off that function while you are writting in your sheet.

try this code before you loop.

```
Application.Screenupdating = False
```

dont forget to turn it on again after you finish your loop

```
Application.Screenupdating = True
```

Another option is to use arrays of string intead of arrays of range wich will surely be slower. you can for example read your brandlist range in a string range and I have not tested it but Im sure if you loop in a string array will be faster

Comment: He is asking for optimization. this has make my loops 100% faster so this is an answer

Comment: brand list 500+ rows, how many rows in reference list?. if they are another 500 that shoul not be a hard work. try turning off your screen. if that does not work try making arrays of string for example: Dim ArrayS(500) as string then fill it with your brang list like this ArrayS(1)=Brandlist(1),ArrayS(2)=Brandlist(2)...ArrayS(i)=Brandlist(i)

Comment: brand list is 500+ rows, but reference list is 100,000+ rows.

Comment: so this mean the code in the loop is runing 500,000+ times. did you tried turning off screen updating?

Comment: you screen is drawing 500,000+ times too so thats the importance of turning off your screen while looping like this

Comment: that means the code in loop is running 500,000,000 times, no?
my excel still crashes after turning screen updating off

Comment: so thats not the best way to do it. try another way. I mean there should be an easier way to achive this

Comment: yes.. i just need help. that's why i am posting this on the forum.

Comment: If you just show your code the only thing everyone can help you is tying to optimize it. but maybe the idea in your code is wrong. Im sure there is an easier way but with another code/method

Comment: Thats why am asking for data example

Comment: how do i upload a file or screenshot?

Comment: you cant because of your reputation. Update your post with a description of what you want to do. so some users can help you. avoid adding too much coments here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Sub Splitter_Step1a()

    Dim RefSheet As Worksheet
    Set RefSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RefList")
    Dim ProdSheet As Worksheet
    Set ProdSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products")

    Dim Brand, LastBrand, BrandList As Range
    Set LastBrand = RefSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    Set BrandList = RefSheet.Range(RefSheet.Range("A1"), LastBrand)

    Dim Reference, ReferenceList, LastReference As Range
    Set LastReference = ProdSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)
    Set ReferenceList = ProdSheet.Range(ProdSheet.Range("C2"), LastReference)

    Dim BrandInList As Boolean, i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 0

    'Part 1a - assigning brand references to product
    For Each Brand In BrandList
        For Each Reference In ReferenceList
            If InStr(1, Reference, Brand, 1) And IsEmpty(Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
                Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
                BrandInList = True
            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
                If InStr(1, Reference, Brand, 1) Then

                Reference.EntireRow.Insert
                Reference.Offset(1, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
                BrandInList = True
                End If
            Else
                BrandInList = False
            End If
        Next Reference

        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Working: " & i & "/" & UBount(BrandList) 'Update scree to show that the Sub is working
            DoEvents
        End If

    Next Brand
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**PS**: Maybe instead of InsertRow you can write in the last row and at the end you can sort the Column again. InsertRow can take much time.

Answer (score 1):

First,Having excel evaluate expression multiple times add loads, so try to store in some variable.
Second, For next loop is very expensive in terms of processing
Third, I see that you are using BrandinList to set true and false but I don't see if you are using it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand but can you use a find for your Reference and only use a loop for your Brand. This might not be perfect but something like:

```
Sub Splitter_Step1a()
Dim i
Dim RefSheet As Worksheet
Set RefSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RefList")
Dim ProdSheet As Worksheet
Set ProdSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Products")

Dim Brand, LastBrand, BrandList As Range
Set LastBrand = RefSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set BrandList = RefSheet.Range(RefSheet.Range("A1"), LastBrand)

Dim Reference, ReferenceList, LastReference As Range
Set LastReference = ProdSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)
Set ReferenceList = ProdSheet.Range(ProdSheet.Range("C2"), LastReference)

Dim BrandInList As Boolean

'Part 1a - assigning brand references to product
For Each Brand In BrandList
With ProdSheet.Range(ReferenceList)
    Set c = .Find(Brand, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        i = 0
        Do
            i = i + 1
            If i = 1 Then
                Reference.Offset(0, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
                Reference.EntireRow.Insert
                Reference.Offset(1, 1).Value = Brand.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
Next Brand

End Sub
```

Also might want to turn application.calculation to manual at the beginning and then turn it back on at the end. This is especially true if you have a lot of lookups in the workbook.